# fName.substring out of bounds

Tags: java, eclipse

```
public class Registration {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

            final String MY_DELIMITER = "','";
            boolean tryAgain = true;
            String fName = "";
            String A = fName.substring(0,2);
            String lName = "";
            int lNameLength = lName.length();
            String B = lName.substring(lNameLength-4,lNameLength);
            String address = "";
            String zip = "";
            String C = zip.substring(0,5);
            String age = "";
            String D = age.substring(0,1);
            String gender = "";
            String race = "";
            String regList = "";
            Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            boolean showList = false;

        // Get input from the user until they type "q"     
        // For each input check for "q"
        // if not q, append the input 
        // to the existing String + the delimiter      
        while(tryAgain)
        {
              System.out.println("Name:  (q to quit)");
              fName = myScanner.nextLine();
              System.out.println("Last Name:  (q to quit)");
              lName = myScanner.nextLine();
              System.out.println("Addess:  ");
              address = myScanner.nextLine();   
              System.out.println("Age:  ");
              age = myScanner.nextLine();
              System.out.println("Gender:  ");
              gender = myScanner.nextLine();
              System.out.println("Race:  ");
              race = myScanner.nextLine();

            if(fName.equals("q"))
            {
                    tryAgain = false;
            }
            else 
            {
                // Append new name to the list using a delimiter
                regList = fName + lName + "\n" + address + "\n" + age + "\n" + gender + "\n" + race + MY_DELIMITER;
            }         
        } // end of while( )

        System.out.println("Here is your registration:" + regList);
        // Convert the String into an array, using the same delimiter 
        String[ ] regArray = regList.split(MY_DELIMITER);

        // Ask the user if they want to display the contents of the array
        // If "y" then display the list using a foreach loop
        System.out.println("Would you like to see the registration from the Array? [y-n]");
        fName = myScanner.nextLine( );

        myScanner.close();

        fName = fName.toLowerCase( );

        showList = fName.equals("y")?true:false;

        if(showList)
        {
            // Display the results using for each
            System.out.println("Here is your registration from the array: ");
            // Use a for each statement instead of the more complex for( ) loop
            // for(int counter=0; counter < employeeArray.length; counter++)
            for(String thisReg:regArray)
            {
                    System.out.println(thisReg); 
                    System.out.printf("USER ID: ", A + "-" + B + "-" + C + "-" + D);
            }
        } // end of if(showList)
    }
}
```

I am trying to extract out the first 3 letters of the fName input, so I figured I could use fName.substring to do that, but it gives me this error.

Sorry I didn't add all of my code, to save time. Apparently it looked confusing. Any way so the fName input is the name of the user. Can it not be in that order?

Comment: What do you think should be the first three letters of an *empty* string?..

Comment: What's the input for name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Erm...your sequence of operations is suspect.  Everywhere, actually.

Look at the following interaction:

```
String fName = "";
String A = fName.substring(0,2);
```

You declare an empty string, then *immediately* take the substring of it.  Where are you getting the data for the substring from?  There's nothing to substring here - the empty string  has a length of zero.

You should be ***certain*** that you're putting data into your string before taking a substring of it.  Using a `Scanner` would go a long way here.

Or better yet, moving your instance of `myScanner` at the top of `main` would make it much clearer as to where that's supposed to go, and how it's supposed to work.

Answer (score 0):

Always check the length of string before substring anything. Especially when a user is giving you this variable.

Comment: Maybe I don't see it, but how is the program getting the values to begin with?

Comment: I am new to java (obv.), I am used to declaring variables at the be gining of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get a substring of an empty string.

```
String fName = "";
String A = fName.substring(0,2); // here fName is empty!!!
```

Change fName into some actual `String` and also check for length of the `String` before calling substring to make sure substring of the size you want exists.

```
String fName = "somestring";
if(fName.length() >= 2) {
    String A = fName.substring(0,2);
    System.out.println(A); // prints out "so"
}
```

That is the case with all of your other `String`s as well.